# Bluetooth lag after wake up from sleep on OS X Ventura

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I'm running OS X Ventura 13.1 on a Mac Book Pro 16-Inch 2021 with M1 chip.

Usually, I have my keyboard (Keychron K8 Pro), my mouse (Razer Naga Hyperspeed), and my headset (Bose Quiet Comfort 35), all three connected via Bluetooth to the mac book.
All works fine without any issues, till my mac goes to sleep. When I wake up the mac all the 3 devices are still connected via Bluetooth, but they "lag" a lot. The mouse pointer is super laggy, and in the music there are interferences. If I shutdown Bluetooth or kill the process with

```
sudo pkill bluetoothd
```

all return to work fine.
This is quite annoying. Does anyone have this problem and can help me to solve this?

ps: I have disabled the headset mic by selecting the MacBook internal microphone from the sound settings.

Comment: Did you try any process-of-elimination troubleshooting to see if the problem is triggered by a certain device being connected?

Comment: Yes, this happens even with just any connected device.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is notoriously finicky, but I believe this could be caused due to changes made with Bluetooth in the latest macOS Ventura 13.1 update. According to the enterprise notes, Apple fixed an issue that "in which the network intermittently became unresponsive in dense Wi-Fi environments".

A few months back, multiple [organizations](https://www.meter.com/mac-osx-awdl-psa) and educational institutions, including [UC Berkeley](https://technology.berkeley.edu/news/software-update-impacting-wi-fi-apple-devices) and [UCLA](https://ucla.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=KB0013801), reported that they were experiencing extreme network packet loss when the network environment was congested AND when devices had Bluetooth & AWDL (Apple Wireless Direct Link — which powers AirDrop and AirPlay) enabled. I also experienced these issues first hand.

What I suspect happened with the latest update is that Apple somehow recalibrated things so Wi-Fi connections have taken priority over Bluetooth connections. While my Wi-Fi issues have been resolved, I have noticed temporarily increased Bluetooth input latency (mouse and keyboard) and audio interference when I re-entered a dense network environment.

Your issue might be unrelated though. What I would suggest is to try changing different variables and see how they change things — such as disabling WiFi when you put your computer to sleep, [disabling AWDL](https://www.meter.com/mac-osx-awdl-psa), [enabling / disabling power nap](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-power-nap-on-or-off-mh40774/13.0/mac/13.0), and switching your WiFi from 2.4 GHz to 5 GHz or vice versa.

Comment: This happens also with wifi turned off.